# vb.net 32 bit vs 64 bit controls become disabled

Tags: vb.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am working on a vb.net winforms application that compiles against the 2.0 framework.  My issue is that I am running Windows 7 32 bit machine and my app works fine but when the code is copied over to a Windows 7 64 bit machine some of the controls on the form are strangely disabled.  In Project Properties it is set to compile as x86 target.  Has anyone experienced a similar problem and does anyone have an answer as to why I am having problems on the 64 bit machine?

Answer (score -1):

Set it to compile to `Any CPU` instead of `x86`. The framework will deal with the rest for you, you should only target a platform if you have references/controls that require it or if you're playing around with application performance.